# Remove a file that has been uploaded in js

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a .js file where you can upload a file or multiple files. I need to also be able to remove the file after it has been uploaded. I am not so familiar with this code yet.

here is the code for the upload:

```
onChooseStepImageClicked: function(btn, e){
var form = btn.up('form'),
    grid = this.getGridProcess(),
    selectedRecord = grid.getSelectionModel().getLastSelected(),
    processid = selectedRecord.get('processid'),
    win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',{
        title:'Image',
        modal:true, constrain:true, stateful:true,
        width:600, height:400,
        layout:'fit',
        items:[
            {
            border:false,
            xtype:'plupload',
            _url : 'data/upload.processimagemap.php',
            _resize : {width : 600, height : 600, quality : 90},
            _unique_names : false,
            _multi_selection : false,
            _filters : [{title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,jpeg,gif,png"}]
            }
             ],
        buttons:[
            {text:'Upload', handler:function(btn){
            var win = btn.up('window'),
                uploader = win.down('plupload').uploader;
                if (uploader.files && uploader.files.length > 0) {
                uploader.settings.multipart_params = {processid:processid};
                uploader.processid = processid;
                uploader.form = form;
                uploader.win = win;
                uploader.bind('UploadComplete', function(up, files) {
                up.form.doLoad(processid);
                uploader.destroy();
                up.win.close();
            });
            uploader.start();
        }else{
        Ext.Msg.alert('','Please select a file to upload.');
        }
    }},
    {text:'Close', handler:function(){ win.close(); }}
    ],
    listeners:{
        beforeclose:function(win){
          win.down('plupload').uploader.destroy();
        }
    }
});
win.show();
},


{

title:'Image',
layout: 'fit',
border: false,
items: {
disabled: (canEditProcess) ? false : true,
    xtype:'form',
formId:'form_step_image',
    tbar:[{iconCls:'image_add', text:'Choose Image', name:'choose_step_image'}, {iconCls:'image_add', text:'Remove Image', name:'remove_step_image'}],
border:false,
autoScroll:true,
bodyPadding:20,
items:[{xtype:'image', src:'', name:'step_image'}],
doLoad:function(processid){
       var f = this, formImg = f.down('image');
   f.getForm().load({
   url:'data/load.processimage.php',
   params:{processid: processid},
   success:function(f,a){
   var data = Ext.JSON.decode(a.response.responseText);
    formImg.setSrc(data.data.image);
   }
     });
    }
  }
},
```

and have:

```
 'button[name=choose_step_image]': {
click: this.onChooseStepImageClicked
 },

 'button[name=remove_step_image]': {
click: this.onRemoveStepImageClicked
 },
```

How shall I go about removing the file i just uploaded?
I am not so familiar with js yet, this is a a bit advanced :)
thanks

Comment: It seems you're dealing with `Ext.JS` and not with `Ember.js`? Do you have an ID or the filename which you could return upon a successful upload? If so you could provide a `<form/>` which gets this parameter set and calls your backend to remove the file, identified by its filename/id ...

Comment: I also have the code where i have my button, please see OP

Comment: I'd suggest you change your tags and replace `ember.js` with `extjs` or `extjs4` (guess you work with `Ext.js` 4, right?) just to have your question tagged right. As for where to get the filename/id: the backend(?) is asked to store the image within the `doLoad()` function of the *unnamed* object you posted. so, if you return the filename/id of the uploaded image from your backend on successful operation you could access it within the `success` callback...